# Updating dynamoDB from dashboard, getting ConditionalCheckFailedException

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Im updating an item which has among other things a map string -> string.

```
id: 12312
locales: Map {
  "en": "Hello",
  "fr": "Bonjour"
}
```

Im trying to edit "Bonjour" and replace with something else, but dynamo fails with ConditionalCheckFailedException.

Im doing this **from the Dashboard**, not from code.

Interestingly I have another table with a map and in that table I had no problem updating a value.

I have tried to remove the "fr" line and insert a new line but Im still getting an error. I haven't tried to remove, save, then insert, because this is prod, live data. Any idea what could be going wrong ? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I think I got it. The item Im trying to update is very popular and being updated pretty frequently. That's why I can't update it from dynamo's dashboard

Comment: No, see my answer.

Comment: @BobDoolittle sorry but this was correct. your answer provides some insights on some other problems but from the dashboard (=the web page) you can edit items and this was done without including conditional expressions. conditional expressions are set AT THE TIME your update an item, they don't "live with an item"

Comment: A reference would be great, because I'd like to understand this. According to the docs I can find, CCF Exception should only occur when a ConditionExpression fails. Here's my reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html What reference supports your conclusion that it can also occur due to update frequency/conflict?

Comment: @BobDoolittle no reference, simple guess. I cannot try now (Im in holidays) but if you open two browser tabs, you edit an item in one tab, we could check if you can edit the same item in the other tab after that. Maybe dynamo has a hidden "version" field or something like that that produces the CCFE? Also I understand your reasoning (the doc says only this creates this error) but I did a basic update on a basic item with no "protocol", from dynamo's dashboard, so there must be something else

Comment: I got an answer from an Amazonian. Although the docs don't mention it, when you do an Edit Item/Save from the AWS DDB dashboard, the Save implicitly sets a Conditional Expression to match the values when you hit Edit. If it's changing while you are editing, you will get a CCF. So if it's just being read a lot, no issue. But if it's being updated a lot this can happen. You can use the browser tools to see the request actually being sent by the dashboard to illustrate this.

Comment: I deleted my incorrect answer so nobody gets confused by it.